# react-native Android Studio Cannot find runner for Text911MobileApp

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When I try to run my app in Android Studio (, it says Cannot find runner for Text911MobileApp

Android Studio Version is:
Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.9971841, built on April 19, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.6
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 3072M
Cores: 8
Metal Rendering is ON

```
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    debugger.watches.in.variables=false
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.instant.shutdown=false
    gradle.version.catalogs.dynamic.support=true
```

Here are all the ANDROID* lines in my .zshrc:

```
 ANDROID_HOME=/Users/susancrayne/Library/Android/sdk
 ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/susancrayne/Library/Android/sdk
 ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/Users/susancrayne/.android/avd
```

So I tried to run an emulator from the command line:

pwd: /Users/susancrayne/AndroidSdkR20.0.3/tools

susancrayne@MacBook-Pro tools % ./emulator -list-avds

```
My_Galaxy_S8_API_30
Pixel_3_API_30
Pixel_XL_API_30
Pixel_XL_API_31
Pixel_XL_API_31_google
```

susancrayne@MacBook-Pro tools % ./emulator -avd Pixel_3_API_30
PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/Users/susancrayne/Library/Android/sdk]!

Clearly the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is set in the environment.  So what is wrong here?  Thanks for any help.